# To return a list from Database using a custom Item Reader in spring batch

Tags: spring-batch

I have a custom item reader to return a list of records from table.My job is running in an infinite loop as the reader contract is not met.Any suggestions on this pls?

```
public class customReader implements ItemReader<List<T>>{


@Autowired
customDao customDao;


static List<T> CCTransDlyLg = null;

 @Override
    public List<T> read() throws Exception {
         if(CCTransDlyLg==null || (CCTransDlyLg!=null && CCTransDlyLg.size()==0)){
             CCTransDlyLg=customDao.getList();      
         }
             log.info("CCTransDlyLg List:"+CCTransDlyLg.size());
        return CCTransDlyLg.size()==0 ? null : CCTransDlyLg;

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're list never changes.  Assuming you read a list that is size 5, your return statement will always return that same list.  The logic of your `ItemReader` looks like you only want to return a single list (aka one call to the `read()` method).

Answer (score 1):

As per Spring Batch Reader contract your method will be called again and again till it returns null.In your code  if customDao succeeds your list will be always of Same Size it will never be zero. You need some condition to break out of that loop and return null .This is one possible solution by using a variable called index to break out of that loop.

On other note i see Mike answered your question i learned spring batch from his book and video itself :)

```
public class customReader implements ItemReader<List<T>> {


private static List<T> CCTransDlyLg = null;
@Autowired
customDao customDao;
private int index = 0;

@Override
public List<T> read() throws Exception {
    if (CCTransDlyLg == null || (CCTransDlyLg != null && CCTransDlyLg.size() == 0)) {
        CCTransDlyLg = customDao.getList();
        index = CCTransDlyLg.size() + 1;
    }
    log.info("CCTransDlyLg List:" + CCTransDlyLg.size());
    return index > CCTransDlyLg.size() ? null : CCTransDlyLg;

}
```